# How to change reference of named range?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to move the row reference of a named range by the result of an operation, for example:
`Sheets("Data").Range("Range1").Offset(a-b, 0)`

What is the syntax I must use to successfully change:
Range1=$A$100 to Range1=$A$(100+(a-b))?

Appreciate any help

Edit:
Sure Scott, I am trying to reset a RowMarker named range back to it's original value but can't get the syntax correct:

Above this sub, I have this:

```
Public lngRowData As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngData As Range
Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange
If lngRowData = 0 Then
lngRowData = rngData.Row
    Exit Sub
End If
If rngData.Row = lngRowData Then Exit Sub
If rngData.Row < lngRowData Then
    MsgBox lngRowData - rngData.Row & " rows removed, repairing formulas"
Else
    MsgBox rngData.Row - lngRowData & " rows added, repairing formulas"
End If
lngRowData = rngData.Row
```

`End Sub`

I will insert it into the if statements below so that the result between lngRowData and rngData.row becomes the offset.

Thank you guys

Comment: there are many ways to do this; but the easiest will depend on the rest of your setup. please show more code, especially how `a` and `b` get defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item("Range1").RefersTo = "=Data!" & Range("Range1").Offset(a - b, 0).Address
```

Comment: Thank you CLR, I will give it a shot and let you know!

Comment: Works great CLR, my original codes had alot of tweaking to do, but the part you provided worked perfect...thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found `RefersToRange` rather a faff so here is another approach.

```
Sub x()

Dim a As Long, b As Long

a = 50
b = 10

With Sheets("Data")
    .Range("A100").Name = "Range1"
    Debug.Print Range("Range1").Address 'A100
    .Range("Range1").Offset(a - b, 0).Name = "Range1"
    Debug.Print Range("Range1").Address 'A140
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR, thank you for the working solution, is there a reason not to use RefersToRange?

Comment: My only reason is that I like an easy life and it seems an unnecessary complication.